# How can modify method initializeProductCollection() without changing in core file

Tags: magento2.2, blocks, product-list

In the class Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct, **how can we modify private
method  "initializeProductCollection()"** without changing anything in this core file?

Please help!!!

Comment: You need to override it in your custom module.

Comment: This is private method.we can't override.

Comment: @SukumarGorai, can you pls update the code, how to override the category loaded product collection?

Answer (score 1):

@wakar Yes , we can not override private method but we can override all the methods of that class which is public and using that private method .

> we need to usually override all methods that call the private method
>   you change and replace the call .

for example

initializeProductCollection() has been called under _getProductCollection() which is protected and that function is called under getLoadedProductCollection() which is public so override that function/method . and create your own method _MygetProductCollection and MyinitializeProductCollection() and make the changes you want to make .

something like this will help , I have not tested the code

di.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Product\ListProduct" />
</config>
```

your class file at location Vendor\Module\Block\Product\ListProduct.php

```
<?php
    class ListProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
    {
        public function MyinitializeProductCollection(){

        }

        public function  _MygetProductCollection(){
    // make changes here means call MyinitializeProductCollection in place of initializeProductCollection
        }

        public function getLoadedProductCollection(){
            // make changes here means call _MygetProductCollection in place of _getProductCollection
        }
    }
```

hope this helps .

Comment: This is not working for me..

Comment: @jafarpinjar 
are you getting any error?

Comment: the code seems not fully given, pls update complete code

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code, for reference here, before return of collection we have just added complete category collection through Category Factory.

```
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Block\Rewrite\Product;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;

class ListProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
{
    protected $_customerSession;
    protected $categoryFactory;

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data $urlHelper,
    array $data = [],
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory
    ) {
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
        $this->_helper = $helper;
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $postDataHelper,
            $layerResolver,
            $categoryRepository,
            $urlHelper,
            $data
        );

    }

    private function initializeProductCollection()
    {
        $layer = $this->getLayer();
        /* @var $layer Layer */
        if ($this->getShowRootCategory()) {
            $this->setCategoryId($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getRootCategoryId());
        }

        // if this is a product view page
        if ($this->_coreRegistry->registry('product')) {
            // get collection of categories this product is associated with
            $categories = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('product')
                ->getCategoryCollection()->setPage(1, 1)
                ->load();
            // if the product is associated with any category
            if ($categories->count()) {
                // show products from this category
                $this->setCategoryId($categories->getIterator()->current()->getId());
            }
        }

        $origCategory = null;
        if ($this->getCategoryId()) {
            try {
                $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($this->getCategoryId());
            } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
                $category = null;
            }

            if ($category) {
                $origCategory = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
                $layer->setCurrentCategory($category);
            }
        }
       
            $categoryId = $this->getLayer()->getCurrentCategory()->getId();

            $category =  $this->categoryFactory->load($categoryId);
            $collection = $category->getProductCollection()
                                ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        
        // $collection = $layer->getProductCollection();
         
        $this->prepareSortableFieldsByCategory($layer->getCurrentCategory());

        if ($origCategory) {
            $layer->setCurrentCategory($origCategory);
        }

        $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
            'catalog_block_product_list_collection',
            ['collection' => $collection]
        );

        return $collection;
    }


}
```

P.S-Please correct i am wrong as i am newbie.